# Feature repo add in KARAF Error Resolving Artifact : Could not read from local repo

Tags: maven-plugin, apache-karaf, karaf-maven-plugin, apache-karaf-feature

```
Error executing command: Error resolving artifact 
com.sample:features:xml:features:4.1.4-SNAPSHOT: 
\[Could not find artifact com.sample:features:xml:features:4.1.4-SNAPSHOT in default 
local (file:/C:{/Users}.m2/repository/), 
Could not find artifact com.sample:features:xml:features:4.1.4-SNAPSHOT in apache 
(https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/), 
Could not find artifact com.sample:features:xml:features:4.1.4-SNAPSHOT
in ops4j.sonatype.snapshots.deploy 
(https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ops4j-snapshots/)\] : 
com.sample:features:xml:features:4.1.4-SNAPSHOT.
```

**I could not resolve this error after uncommenting local repository in org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn and add my local .m2 path**

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**You might have to reset your Apache karaf instance to fresh state.**

1. Stop Karaf
2. Delete data folder from Karaf installation folder.
3. Start Karaf
4. Re-Install the features and bundles you need.

Alternatively you can try removing any features, feature-repositories and bundles that have been installed from there before removing the maven repository.

It's generally bad idea to remove/replace maven repositories from Apache Karaf from where user(s) might have already added new feature repositories, installed features and bundles.

Once tried to replace offline repository I had made with a new one which was missing some older artifacts. This lead to bunch of issues like inability to uninstall some of the older features.

Comment: Hey Man! - Thanks for your suggestion. I will try as you say.